# Change PIN mapping for UART in the code for nRF51

Tags: c, microcontroller, nrf51

While communicating with one serial device, I would like to send some information to another serial device (after finished with the first one). How can I change pin mapping (my own built boards) for UART while running the code for nRF51822 (g_ADigitalPinMap)?